# Deploy Django on AWS Elastic Beanstalk cannot connect to sql server

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to deploy django on to AWS EB. I have a RDS linked to the instance and database is migrated without any problem.
When I log onto the server using ssh and try to create a superuser, I run into following errors:
**django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)")**

I used the same setup for several other django site, didn't have the same problem.
The only difference this time is in the view I'm using native sql, I wonder if the connection.cursor() is causing this problem.

In settings I have:

```
if 'RDS_HOSTNAME' in os.environ:
    print "live site server connection: ", os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME']
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
            'OPTIONS': {
                'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
            },
            'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
            'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
            'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
            'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': 'new_dash',
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': '',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': '3306',
        }
    }




/opt/python/run/venv/bin/python manage.py createsuperuser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 63, in execute
    return super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 342, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 30, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1266, in check
    errors.extend(cls._check_fields(**kwargs))
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1337, in _check_fields
    errors.extend(field.check(**kwargs))
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 893, in check
    errors = super(AutoField, self).check(**kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 208, in check
    errors.extend(self._check_backend_specific_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 311, in _check_backend_specific_checks
    return connections[db].validation.check_field(self, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 41, in check_field
    field_type = field.db_type(connection)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 629, in db_type
    return connection.data_types[self.get_internal_type()] % data
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 183, in data_types
    if self.features.supports_microsecond_precision:
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/features.py", line 54, in supports_microsecond_precision
    return self.connection.mysql_version >= (5, 6, 4) and Database.version_info >= (1, 2, 5)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 367, in mysql_version
    with self.temporary_connection() as cursor:
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 564, in temporary_connection
    cursor = self.cursor()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 231, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 204, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 171, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 263, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)")
```